# Is it possible in Scipy.optimize to get the optimized array as an array of integers?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm doing a program using Scipy.optimize with method SLSQP to minimize an objective function. However, the optimized array I get is an array of floats but I would like elements to be integers (they are Electric powers).

Can SLSQP make an integer optimization and if yes how can I do it ?

I guess taking the integral part of my elements and making an integer optimization would lead to different results in some cases...

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: I know there is Pulp library for such integer programming but my function is non linear then I don't think it is possible to do it with Pulp